# Lodash excludes items when trying to filter with an undefined property

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am using lodash `_.where` to filter an array. When a property of `filters` is undefined, lodash tries matching the undefined value instead of ignoring the property entirely.

```
var list = [{
    type: 'something',
    units: [{bar: 1}]
}];
var filters = {};


var filteredlist = _(list)
.where(filters.type ? { 
  type: filters.type
} : {})
.where(filters.view === 'foo' && filters.bar ? { 
  units: [{
    bar: +filters.bar
  }]
} : {})
.value();
filteredlist;
```

The above returns the lone item in `list`.

But I must check if the property in `filters` exists before using `_.where` or `_.filter` to filter my `list`.

If I simply did:

```
var filteredlist = _(list)
.where({ 
  type: filters.type,
  units: [{
    bar: +filters.bar
  }]
})
.value();
```

I get nothing back because `filters.type` and `filters.bar` are not defined...

Is there a native way I can have lodash let items pass through `_.where` or `_.filter` (or an alternative) if the properties i'm trying to filter by are undefined or falsy? Preferably without a mixin, but if you've got an elegant solution, feel free to share.

Comment: Do you need to check if every key in each list's object exists in filters, or just a couple of specific ones?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be in the ballpark for what you're looking for:

```
_(list).filter(function (item) {
  return _.has(filters, 'type') ? _.isEqual(filters.type, item.type) : true;
}).value()
```

However if you need to check against all keys in filters, then you might need this instead:

```
_(list).filter(function (item) {
  var pass = true;
  _.each(filters, function (v, k) {
      if (!_.isEqual(item[k], v)) { 
          pass = false;
      }
  });
  return pass;
}).value()
```